How to Implement Secure API Key-Based Authentication and Authorization for External Systems?
I'm designing an API (dot net core API) that will be consumed by external systems (mostly servers), that need access to specific endpoints. For instance, my API has the following endpoints:
/users
/applications
/clients

I need to ensure that:

External System A can only access /users and /applications
External System B can only access /users and /clients

I want to implement a secure authentication and authorization system using API keys (want to avoid OAuth).
Current Approach

Using API Keys for Authentication


API Key Generation: Generate and assign a unique API key for each external system.
API Key Storage: Store the API keys securely in your database along with the associated system and its permissions.

{
  "api_key": "api_key_A",
  "role": "SystemA_Role"
}


Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) for Authorization
Define roles based on the access requirements of each external system.
Permission Mapping: Map each role to the specific endpoints it is allowed to access.

{
  "roles": {
    "SystemA_Role": {
      "endpoints": [
        "/counterparties",
        "/assessments"
      ]
    },
    "SystemB_Role": {
      "endpoints": [
        "/counterparties",
        "/reports "
      ]
    }
  }
}

**Questions: **

Is this approach as per industry standard, secure and scalable for production environments?
Also, is there any possibility to store these keys securely using the Azure key vault service?


Here's a sample I found about API key. Just like you see, it creates a middleware to validate the key contained in httpcontext. We can know the incoming url, the key so that we could know whether we should let the request continue.

Is this approach as per industry standard, secure and scalable for
production environments.

It depends, let's say the application/system we are trying to realize is really simple and stable, then it's good I think to use API key. But if the system might become more and more complex, then I'm afraid this is not a good option, as the key itself doesn't contain any extra information. Comparing with JWT token, the token itself containing much information which can be used to validate many other information.
store these keys securely using the Azure key vault service

Definitely ok, Azure Key vault provides us a new approach to store secret keys. What we need to to do is adding Authentication into the application so that the application could connect to Azure key vault. For example, just like the middleware in the sample I shared above, we can add codes below to get the key stored in Azure keyVault. We use DefaultAzureCredential to pass the authentication.
const string secretName = "clientsecret";
var kvUri = "https://keyvaultname.vault.azure.net/";
var a = new DefaultAzureCredential();
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), a);
var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
string secretVaule = secret.Value.Value;

I prefer jwt authorization anyway.
